# Non measurable function but measurable pre-image

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having trouble with a problem. It gives a hint to use the Vitali construction, but I honestly do not understand it.

The question is: Show that there is a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not Lebesgue measurable, but $\forall$ $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ $f^{-1}(a)$ is measurable.

My try: 
Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , and

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x & x\in E \\
      -x & x\notin E
     \end{cases}
$

I am not certain that this is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and all apologies for the simplistic inquiries.

Comment: Your example is nice and simple. But to make it work you must choose $E$ with some care:  1. $E$ must be symmetric with respect to $0$ (then for all $a$, $f^{-1}(a)$ is a singleton). 2. Both $E\cap (0, +\infty)$ and  $E\cap (-\infty, 0)$ must be non-measurable.  Then $f^{-1}((0,+\infty))= (E\cap (0, +\infty)) \cup ((-\infty, 0)-E)$  and it is to see that $(E\cap (0, +\infty)) \cup ((-\infty, 0)-E)$ is non-measurable. So $f$ is non-measurable.

Comment: An easy way to build $E$ satisfying the two conditions is:  take $D\subseteq [0,1]$ such that $D$ is non-measurable. Then define 
$$E= D \cup \{-x \,|\, x\in D\} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself has measurable preimages of singletons. So a straightforward way to do it is to biject a nonmeasurable set $E$ with an interval $I$, and then biject $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ with $\mathbb{R} \setminus I$. Then the preimage of the interval is $E$ which is certainly not measurable.

What Borel set has nonmeasurable preimages in your example? (I am not claiming it does not work, I am just not entirely clear how it works, if it does work.)

Edit: a variant on your example which more obviously works: let $E$ be a nonmeasurable set contained in $(0,\infty)$, then define

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
x & x \in E \\
-x & x \in [0,\infty) \setminus E \\
x & x \in (-\infty,0) \end{cases}.$$

Then $f^{-1}(\{ a \})$ is either empty, a singleton, or two points, but $f^{-1}((0,\infty))=E$ which is not measurable.

Comment: I have no idea, it was what I thought of with my limited understanding of the material. I cannot quite get an example with your hint, but I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: @Krampus My hint is quite nonconstructive, because it does not say how to furnish a bijection between a nonmeasurable set and an interval. However, it is not so hard to see that the cardinality of a Vitali set is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}$, and this is enough to give a nonconstructive proof. (The gist of that argument: a union of countably many disjoint Vitali sets contains an interval, so $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{N}| \cdot |V|=\max \{ |\mathbb{N}|,|V| \}=|V|$, where in the second to last step I have used the axiom of choice.)

Comment: I think I see that, but I am trying to construct such a function. Any pointers?

Comment: @Krampus I think $f(x)=x$ for $x \in E$ is a good idea. Here is an idea for how to deal with the rest of the line: take a nonmeasurable set of *positive* numbers, then send $x \in E$ to itself, $x \in [0,\infty) \setminus E$ to $-x$, and $x \in (-\infty,0)$ to itself. Then every point has at most two preimages, and the preimage of $[0,\infty)$ is $E$.

Comment: Thank you. I was not trying to get an explicit answer, because I am trying to learn, but all the help is appreciated.

Comment: @Krampus You're welcome. Technically my example actually *is* your example, but with a carefully chosen $E$ (namely, half of the line plus a nonmeasurable set contained in the other half of the line). So I do not think that this is an unreasonable amount of help.

Comment: The example originally proposed by @Krampus works. It is enough to choose $E$ with some care:  It is enough to take  $E$  symmetric with respect to $0$ and such that both $E\cap (0, +\infty)$ and  $E\cap (-\infty, 0)$ must be non-measurable.

Comment: @Ramiro As I said, my final example is an instance of Krampus' example with a particular class of $E$ (different from the class you've suggested, actually).

Comment: I understand you. I have just highlighted  that @Krampus original example is perfectly fine, provided some very simple care is taken when choosing $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Nice example.  Each $f^{-1}(a)$ is a singleton (hence measurable) but $f$ is not measurable.

[Added: As @John Ma notes, $f^{-1}(a)$ need not be a singleton, but does have cardinality at most 2.  To see the non-measurability of $f$, let $g$ denote the identity function; then $f=g\cdot (2\cdot 1_E -1)$, where $1_E$ is the indicator function of $E$. If $f$ were measurable, then on ${\Bbb R}\setminus\{0\}$ so too would $1_E = [(f/g)+1]/2$ be measurable, a contradiction of the basic hypothesis.]

Comment: That was my thought, so I am correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: $f^{-1}(a)$ is actually not a singleton. It might have two points. Also, can you also show why such an $f$ is nonmeasurable?